# Javascript: How do I make a save-file dialog for saving a file?

Tags: javascript

On my website, I am trying to make a button that. when pressed, saves a file. The thing is, I cannot find a way to make a save file dialog.

A save file dialog is the menu that pops up for when you want to save a file. You can pick the file location, change the file name, etc.

It would be more convenient to have a dialog, than to just download the file to the downloads folder.

I have found multiple different StackOverflow questions of the same thing but I could not find one that was not completely outdated/using internet explorer or using some server-using method (Honestly, I don't understand server-side things that much so it went completely over my head and it, too, was over 10 years old, on stack overflow, using Internet Explorer). I found some Chrome API that might work but I don't know how to use, so an explanation to this may also work as-well.

I just want to have the user click a button, and it open a save-file dialog, to save a .zip file on their computer. For context, the file would've already been  made, I don't need to generate a file or blob or whatever.

I do not have any code to share, as I'm not sure what to share.

Comment: not quite understanding your question is the user uploading a file from their computer to your server? or is the user downloading a file from your server (file server?) to their computer

Comment: @BryanDellinger The user should download the file to their computer.

Comment: then the answer would depend on your server side code. what are you using c#, java, python, php?

Comment: @BryanDellinger I have no idea, I host on 000webhost if that helps?

Comment: https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/how-to-make-a-download-section/24423

Comment: @BryanDellinger Yes like that, but with a Save file dialog. Did you read the post at all? I'm trying to make a save file dialog for when saving a file, not just saving a file in general. Sorry if I sound rude.

Comment: then I think you just need to put the word download in your href.  <a href=“http://www.yourdomain.com/downloads/file.zip 4” download">TEXT<a> https://www.philowen.co/blog/force-a-file-to-download-when-link-is-clicked/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://blog.logrocket.com/programmatic-file-downloads-in-the-browser-9a5186298d5c/) explains a few of the ways you can ask the browser to download a file.

If you don't want to set an HTTP header on the server side you can also just add a download attribute to an `a` tag and it will prompt the user to download the content at the href url.

NOTE: The attribute will only work if the origin of the href and the origin of the current page are the same.

```html
<!-- 
You can pass the name you want the file to be saved as in the download attribute 
-->
<a href="/" title="Home Page" download="home.html">Click here to download</a>
```

Comment: ^ When you run the code snippet the download feature isn't working because it's being run inside of an iframe but if you try it out on your actual site it will work

Answer (score 1):

in addition to my comment and Abir's answer in your original post you said you wanted a button. you can always style your link to look like a button with css. here is an example.

```css
a:link, a:visited {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover, a:active {
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!-- 
You can pass the name you want the file to be saved as in the download attribute 
-->
<a href="/" title="Home Page" download="home.html">Click here to download</a>
```